# c++ тип возвращаемого значения функции

Tags: c++, массивы

В этом примере мне нужно вернуть массив `int nums[40]`
Как это сделать?

```
<RETURNTYPE> test()
{
    int nums[40];

    for (int i=0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = i + 1;
    }

    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам надо динамически выделить память в функции и вернуть указатель на этот участок памяти:

```
int* test()
{
    int *nums = new int[40];
    for (int i=0; i < 40; i++)
        nums[i] = i + 1;
    return nums;
}
```

**UPD**

```
struct int_arr_40 {
    int arr[40];
};

int_arr_40 test()
{
    int_arr_40 nums;
    for (int i=0; i < 40; i++)
        nums.arr[i] = i + 1;
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: А без кучи никак? Ведь если `new`, то нужно будет сделать `delete`?

Comment: @ilmirabdulmanov можно завернуть в структуру, а так идей особо больше нет

Comment: @ilmirabdulmanov но в целом если вы используете C++, лучше используйте контейнер из стандартной библиотеки std::array

Answer (score 9):

Так как у нас C++, можно возвращать [std::vector](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) или [std::array](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

```
std::array<int,40> test()
{
    std::array<int,40> nums;
    for (int i=0; i < 40; i++)
        nums[i] = i + 1;
    return nums;
}
```

Учитывая [RVO](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2008/02/rvo-nrvo.html), лишнего копирования элементов не будет.